# Ricoh SDK/J Development

Tags: java, java-me, cdc, xlet

I have a requirement for creating a simple application for showing a text that says Hello World on the Ricoh printer console. I researched and found about the Ricoh SDK/J which is supported on a J2ME environment for developing applications for Ricoh Printers. But I am curious to know is there any other way to create the application using say simple J2ME Midlet application. Will that run on the RICOH printer console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I'm 99% sure there are no other ways of developing apps for Ricoh printers.

What you need to develop is called an Xlet, and they are used in many consumer electronics, like printers, stereos, TV set top boxes, even Blu-ray players run Xlets from Blu-ray discs. (The movie menu stuff you see when you watch a Blu-ray disc).

Xlets may seem a bit complex, because there exists many API's for development. For example, Blu-ray discs have an additional API not available for other Xlets. So you need to figure out which API's are available for Ricoh printers. (Probably just the core basic ones I suspect).

Do a search for "Getting started with Xlets", and I bet you'll get started fairly quick.